# Trying to assign labels based on the values on another column but getting always the same value

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to assign some labels on a column based on the values of another column. The values of the column `'Percentage_delay'` range from 0 to 1. If the value of the column `'Percentage_delay'` is more than 0.75 the corresponding value on the column `'Labels'` is supposed to be `'high'`, if less then 0.75 and more than 0.5 `'medium'`, if less than 0.5 `'low'`.

I have come up with this code:

```
for i in number_delay_aiport['Percentage_delay']:
    if i >= 0 and i < 0.25:
        number_delay_aiport['Labels'] = 'low'
    if i >= 0.25 and i < 0.75:
        number_delay_aiport['Labels'] = 'medium'
    if i >= 0.75 and i <= 1:
        number_delay_aiport['Labels'] = 'high'
```

The output is wrong, since I have only the `Label == 'high'`:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGzyC.png)

The same happens if I use the `'return'` function.

Could you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: Column of what? Presumably a dataframe but you didn't add the pandas tag, and you shouldn't be iterating the df if that's the case (nor is it the correct way to do so)

Comment: Looks like you are iterating over an input array `number_delay_aiport['Percentage_delay']` but only storing on a single variable `number_delay_aiport['Labels']`, which gets overwritten by the last value. Can you show a little of input data structure and how you print?

Comment: The output you get is the one expected since in every single loop you modify `number_delay_aiport['Labels']`.

Comment: It's difficult to know what is happening prior to this loop. For example, it's possible that `number_delay_aiport['Percentage_delay']` is the same number every time because of some logic (or that is was interpreted as a bool or any other logic issue). Can you please post this code in context? Also, you might consider modifying this to  if..elif...elif...else rather than multiple ifs.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot it seems like you're using a Pandas DataFrame. If this is the case you should use `apply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the for loop to an enumerated for loop and use `iloc` on your labels:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"Percentage_delay" : [0.64, 0.80, 0.55, 0.48, 0.65, 0.46, 0.87, 0.66, 0.77, 0.44]}

number_delay_airport = pd.DataFrame(d)
# to use iloc you first have to create the column
number_delay_airport['Labels'] = ''
for j, i in enumerate(number_delay_airport['Percentage_delay']):
    print(i,j)
    if i >= 0 and i < 0.25:
        number_delay_airport['Labels'].iloc[j] = 'low'
    if i >= 0.25 and i < 0.75:
        number_delay_airport['Labels'].iloc[j] = 'medium'
    if i >= 0.75 and i <= 1:
        number_delay_airport['Labels'].iloc[j] = 'high'

print(number_delay_airport)
```

Or even better, using the `apply` function you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"Percentage_delay" : [0.64, 0.80, 0.55, 0.48, 0.65, 0.46, 0.87, 0.66, 0.77, 0.44]}

number_delay_airport = pd.DataFrame(d)

def assign_label(i):
    if i >= 0 and i < 0.25:
        return 'low'
    if i >= 0.25 and i < 0.75:
        return 'medium'
    if i >= 0.75 and i <= 1:
        return 'high'

number_delay_airport['Labels'] = number_delay_airport['Percentage_delay'].apply(assign_label)

print(number_delay_airport)
```